# What is the most efficient way to merge 2 large lists, based on a timestamp, in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have 2 lists of data, Events and Heartbeats.

```
public class RunEvent : EntityBase
    {
        public DateTime EventDateUtc { get; set; }
        public List<Heartbeat> RelevantHeartbeats { get; set; } = new List<Heartbeat>();
    }
```

```
public class Heartbeat : EntityBase
    {
        public string Image { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime EventDateUtc { get; set; }
    }
```

My goal is to populate the RelevantHeartbeats array for each RunEvent in the list of RunEvents with any Heartbeats that occur +- 1 second within the EventDateUtc of the RunEvent.  Each list can have 100K plus items, so efficiency is paramount.  This is the code I have tried, but it is terribly inefficient:

```
private const double RelevantHeartbeatThresholdMs = 1000;

foreach (var runEvent in runEvents)
            {
                runEvent.RelevantHeartbeats = heartbeats.Where(hb => 
                    runEvent.EventDateUtc > hb.EventDateUtc.AddMilliseconds(RelevantHeartbeatThresholdMs * -1) &&
                    runEvent.EventDateUtc < hb.EventDateUtc.AddMilliseconds(RelevantHeartbeatThresholdMs)).ToList();
            }
```

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: What is the accuracy supposed to be here?  Would it be feasable to group the Heartbeats into buckets indexed by DateTime (truncated to the second)? Then you could have lookups with O(1)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-sort heartbeats. And search for left and right range borders with BinarySearch.

```
var heartbeatsArray = heartbeats.ToArray();
var heartbeatsTime = heartbeats.Select(hb => new DateTime?(hb.EventDateUtc)).ToArray();
Array.Sort(heartbeatsTime, heartbeatsArray);


foreach (var runEvent in runEvents)
{
    var leftTime = runEvent.EventDateUtc.AddMilliseconds(relevantHeartbeatThresholdMs * -1);
    var leftIndex = Array.BinarySearch(heartbeatsTime, leftTime);
    if(leftIndex < 0) leftIndex = ~leftIndex;
    
    var rightTime = runEvent.EventDateUtc.AddMilliseconds(relevantHeartbeatThresholdMs);
    var rightIndex = Array.BinarySearch(heartbeatsTime, rightTime);
    if(rightIndex < 0) rightIndex = ~rightIndex;
    
    runEvent.RelevantHeartbeats = heartbeatsArray[leftIndex..rightIndex].ToList();
}
```

Comment: It's not the most efficient solution.

Comment: @rotabor That's all a matter of opinion and the reason why the question should be closed in it's current state

Comment: @DarkBee really? Do you think so? Would you like to state, that algorithm efficiency has no quantitative measurement?

Comment: @rotabor It's true only if you don't count sorting. With sorting my algo have: $n*log(n) + m*2*log(n)$. And your have: $m*log(m) + n*log(n) + n$. So they are asymptotically the same.

Comment: Looking at your reply to my comment it's seems to be opinionated yes, FWIW I did not downvote your answer, but did you actually benchmark this and your answer side to side before coming to this conclusion?

Comment: @DarkBee I'm going to benchmark them

Comment: @rotabor I'm tested them a little. With sorting and without intersections your solution is faster about 5-10%. With intersections it works about 3 times slower. And without sorting your solution have obviously better asymptomatic, so it have no point to compare directly.

Comment: Nice to cooperate with you!

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient approach is to sort both lists by time then concurrenty run through both lists. Complexity is 2 sorts plus O(n), where "n = min(runEvents.Count, heartBeats.Count)". But, most probable, both lists are already time-ordered, thus only O(n) remains.

Below is the demo where DateTime is replaced by int for demo simplicity. It is assumed that:

1. Both lists are time-ordered
2. If intersection is allowed and a case of interval intersection, Heartbeats add to all RelevantHeartbeats
3. If intersection is not allowed, Heartbeats fall into earliest RelevantHeartbeats.

```
new RelevantTimestamp().Execute().Output(10);
new RelevantTimestamp(true).Execute().Output(10);

class RelevantTimestamp {

    public RelevantTimestamp Execute() {
        int hbi = 0, hbj, hbc = heartbeats.Count;
        foreach (var runevent in runevents) {
            var ctl = runevent.EventDateUtc - 10;
            hbj = hbi;
            while (hbj < hbc && heartbeats[hbj].EventDateUtc < ctl) hbj++;
            if (hbj == hbc) break;
            if (_inters) hbi = hbj;
            ctl = runevent.EventDateUtc + 10;
            while (hbj < hbc && heartbeats[hbj].EventDateUtc <= ctl) runevent.RelevantHeartbeats.Add(heartbeats[hbj++]);
            if (!_inters) { if (hbj == hbc) break; hbi = hbj; }
        }
        return this;
    }

    class EntityBase {
        public int EventDateUtc { get; set; }
    }

    class RunEvent : EntityBase {
        public List<Heartbeat> RelevantHeartbeats { get; set; } = new List<Heartbeat>();
        public RunEvent(int i) { EventDateUtc = i; }
    }

    class Heartbeat : EntityBase {
        public string Image { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Heartbeat(int i) { EventDateUtc = i; }
    }

    bool _inters;
    List<RunEvent> runevents = new List<RunEvent>();
    List<Heartbeat> heartbeats = new List<Heartbeat>();

    public RelevantTimestamp(bool allowintersection = false) {
        _inters = allowintersection;
        var r = new Random(); int d = _inters ? 1 : 21;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 1000; i++) runevents.Add(new RunEvent(j += d + r.Next(100)));
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10000; i++) heartbeats.Add(new Heartbeat(j += 1 + r.Next(10)));
    }

    public void Output(int lim) {
        var l = Math.Min(lim, 1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(runevents[i].EventDateUtc.ToString());
            for (int j = 0; j < runevents[i].RelevantHeartbeats.Count; j++)
                Console.WriteLine(runevents[i].RelevantHeartbeats[j].EventDateUtc.ToString().PadLeft(8));
        }
    }
}
```